# Displaying JSON Data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display my JSON data in my HTML UI,
The JSON Object is returning but I am not able to display the object.

And here is my JSON object structure:

[image]

Here is my JS File:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  // on form submission ...
  $('form').on('submit', function() {

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
    valueTwo = $('input[name="hostname"]').val();
    valueThree = $('input[name="iteration"]').val();


    console.log(valueOne)
    console.log(valueTwo)
    console.log(valueThree)



    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      datatype:'json',
      data : { 'first': valueOne,'second': valueTwo,'third': valueThree},
      success: function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.Exempt)
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

});
```

I get nothing in my result div.

EDIT:

Here is my json.stringify(result)  output on my UI:

[image]

Comment: What is `result` ? Can you show us ? May be `JSON.stringify(result)`

Comment: result is the HTML div on my UI.

Comment: Am asking about the `result` argument being passed in ajax success callback....

Comment: OP, you should change `datatype` to `dataType` in your AJAX call.

Comment: try this in success callback `$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: @RayonDabre

I have attached the JSON.stringify(result) in OP

Comment: $.ajax({ ...options... }, "json"); - will make sure the result is automatically parsed and not subject to mimetype vagueries...

Comment: So many upvotes ? Could not find the reason :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i feel you should stop the form submit:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) { // <-----add arg to get the event as e.
  e.preventDefault(); //<----add this to stop the form submission

  console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

  // grab values
  valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
  valueTwo = $('input[name="hostname"]').val();
  valueThree = $('input[name="iteration"]').val();

  console.log(valueOne)
  console.log(valueTwo)
  console.log(valueThree)

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
      'first': valueOne,
      'second': valueTwo,
      'third': valueThree
    },
    success: function(data) { //<----this confused so change it to "data"
      var res = data.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.Exempt;                 
      var p = '<p><pre>'+res+'</pre></p>';
      $('#result').append(p); // now append the Exempts here.
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  });
});
```

---

Because if you don't then form will submit and page gets refreshed and the data from ajax won't be reflected.

---

#### Updates:

I guess the actual problem lies here:

```
    success: function(data) { //<----this confused so change it to "data"
      var res = data.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.Exempt;                 
      var p = '<p><pre>'+res+'</pre></p>';
      $('#result').append(p); // now append the Exempts here.
    },
```

The most confusing part in the code was the usage of `result` key. Better to have a different name in the success callback as i used `data` which is denoting the response data from ajax which is an object. So we just need to target it like:

```
var res = data.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.Exempt;
```

Comment: @Jai 
Summarystats is present, its just not visible in screenshot.
Sorry.

Comment: @AnkitaDhawale just seen the other screenshot there is `stats` which is an array so you have to loop in it to get the value you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/), this method will transform json to javascript object and after it loop this object and append html to page. Will be better to send array of items instead of object with parameters from server.